# Grabbing a value from a TextView in another activity

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I am wanting to grab the value from a TextView that is on another activity. The TextView is actually pulling a value from a database and displaying the logged in user's name.

I am setting up an contact email activity, I have it working perfectly but I am struggling to pull the users name from the TextView and incorporate it into the email. Here's the code from contact activity...

```
package com.example.empireuslforms;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class GeneralEmailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public EditText mEmailText;
    public Button mSendEmail;
    public TextView mUserName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_general_email);

        mUserName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvUser);
        mEmailText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.etEmailText);
        mSendEmail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnEmailSend);
        mSendEmail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendMail();
            }
        });


    }

    private void sendMail() {

        String user_name = mUserName.getText().toString();
        String mail = "email@email.com";
        String message = "From: " + user_name + "\n" + mEmailText.getText().toString();
        String subject = "Empire Forms App Contact";

        //Send Email
        JavaMailAPI javaMailAPI = new JavaMailAPI(this, mail, subject, message);

        javaMailAPI.execute();
    }
}
```

The TextView on the other activity is called "tvUser".

I have played around with this and managed to get a result in the email that says...

From: null
Then the message typed

But the code you see above, just crashes the app when the send email button is clicked.

Comment: "The TextView is actually pulling a value from a database and displaying the logged in user's name." - So can't you just do the same thing in your other `TextView`...?

Comment: I am not wanting to display the users name again, rather use it as a string to send along with the email. I have tried to do this what you speak of but it failed and I assumed taking a value from the TextView would be easier.

Comment: "I am not wanting to display the users name again, rather use it as a string to send along with the email" - But it's the same value, right? It will be easier to use this than try and access a view in another activity (which is, to be honest, ill-advised for several reasons).

Comment: Do you want to pass that string to the previous activity or start another activity and pass string

Comment: Here you can learn more about passing data through the activities: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Intents-to-Create-Flows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the string through the intent that leads to your new activity.

**Activity A**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this@MainActivity, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key", yourString); //or textView.getText().toString();
startActivity(intent);
```

**Activity B onCreate**:

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

If both activities are not related by intents you should considering save that string in a shared preferences for using it wherever you need it.